# Compiling OpenCV3.0.0 with mingw32-builds

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, mingw32

I've built OpenCV 2.4.8 in the past with the regularly distributed mingw32, but since I'm migrating to use newer C++11 standard functions and OpenCV3 formats and functionalities, I had to change my compiler to *mingw32-builds*.

It certainly supports the C++11 functions I want to use, but I can't compile OpenCV3 properly.

Some other questions suggested two approaches

1. Disabling `WITH_IPP` during CMake
2. Commenting out `add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)` in the CMake configuration file

Although making these modifications made it compile, IPP is a performance enhancing library and that warning message is a high level warning which may lead to future bugs.

Is there anyway to compile OpenCV3.0.0 without these quirks?

Additional information:

- I've already compiled the exact same build on Ubuntu and everything (from c++11 to opencv3) went fine, no errors, no high level warnings, no quirks
- I am now working under Windows 8.1 64-bit, but focused on compiling 32-bit binaries (for compatibility)

Comment: just [don't expect too much](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4352#note-1)

Comment: Will there be any alternative to MinGW, then?